# Mongoose instance method is undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, instance, mongoose

I defined an instance method with Mongoose to authenticate a rep (user):

```
RepSchema.methods.authenticate = function(password){
  return this.encryptPassword(password) === this.hashed_password;
};
```

In my app, I find the rep and call the `authenticate` method on it:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Rep = mongoose.model("Rep");

Rep.findOne({email: email}, function(err, rep){
  if (rep.authenticate(req.body.session.password)){
    req.session.rep_id = rep._id;
    res.redirect('/calls', {});
  }
});
```

However I get this error:

```
TypeError: Object { email: 'meltzerj@wharton.upenn.edu',
  password: XXXXXXXXX,
  name: 'meltz',
  _id: 4fbc6fcb2777fa0272000003,
  created_at: Wed, 23 May 2012 05:04:11 GMT,
  confirmed: false,
  company_head: false } has no method 'authenticate'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @JohnnyHK not sure what relevant code I would be omitting

Comment: @JohnnyHK even if I instantiate a fresh object via `rep = new Rep();` it throws the same error when I call `authenticate` on it

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So I finally figured out what I was doing wrong. The mongoose source code applies all defined methods inside `schema.methods` to the prototype of the model at the point at which the model's schema is set to the model name (`mongoose.model("modelname", modelSchema)`). Therefore, you must define all methods, which adds these methods to the method object of the Schema instance, before you set the model to its name. I was setting the model before defining the methods. Problem solved.