# mongoose instance method is undefined AFTER correctly ordering method definition and schema naming

Tags: node.js, mongoose, instance-methods

I defined an instance method on a schema that I can't seem to access. Before I go into details, I'll say that I have read [this question] ([Mongoose instance method is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10724876/mongoose-instance-method-is-undefined)), which had the same problem, but my root cause must be different.  I defined all instance methods before I connected the model to its name.

First I defined a schema, and then defined an instance method:
    AccountSchema.methods.addFunds = function(amountToAd, callback) { 
        // do some stuff to add funds
        return callback();
    }

At the bottom of that file, I associate the name to the schema:
    var exports = module.exports = Account = mongoose.model('Account', AccountSchema);

For the record, just before associating the schema and name, I checked to make sure that AccountSchema.methods had my instance method.

Later, I use Account.findOne to fetch an instance of an account:

```
AccountSchema.statics.login = function( email, password, callback) { 
Account.findOne({ email:email}, function( err, doc){
        if(err) {
            console.log(err, null);
        } 

        // below is just some stuff to see if the doc is associated to the schema
        if(doc) {
            var keys = Object.keys(doc.schema);
            for(var propertyName in doc.schema) {
            console.log(propertyName + ":  " + doc[propertyName]);
        }
        // blah, do some other stuff
        callback(doc);
    }
}
```

I include the snippet above because it looks like at the time I fetched the account from my db, it no longer has any instance methods.

Finally, when I try to call doc.addFunds, I get:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'addFunds'
```

I'd appreciate any help or a link to a fully complete mongoose schema definition that uses instance methods.

Comment: example: https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/master/examples/doc-methods.js

Answer (score 0):

Should it be something like this instead ?

```
AccountSchema.statics.login = function( email, password, callback) { 
    Account.findOne({ email:email}, function( err, doc){
        if(err) {
            console.log(err, null);
        } 

        if(doc) {
            var keys = Object.keys(doc.schema);
            for(var key in keys) {
                console.log(key + ":  " + doc.schema[key]); // I changed doc[key] to doc.schema[key]
            }
        }
        callback(doc);
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't think that's relevant to the question. OP is not trying to print the keys, but to call an instance method on the document.

Answer (score 0):

You use static method for MODEL but not for INSTANCE (doc):

> AccountSchema.**statics**.login = function( email, password, callback) { ...

but are trying to call for instance (doc) method:

> **doc**.addFunds

You should call to model's like a:

```
AccountSchema.addFunds(...);
```