# Error while authenticating(sign in) password using passport-local module in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js

```
Server running at http://localhost:3000/

/home/sankar/Cloud/config/strategies/local.js:26
        if (!(user.authenticate(password))) 
                   ^
TypeError: Object { firstName: 'raju',
lastName: 'raju',
email: 'raju@070',
username: 'raju',
password: 'raju',
_id: 551b7ca79177c00c1342a3ee,
__v: 0 } has no method 'authenticate'
 at Promise.<anonymous>                 (/home/sankar/Cloud/config/strategies/local.js:26:15)
  at Promise.<anonymous>      (/home/sankar/Cloud/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promis       e.js:177:8)
  at Promise.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
  at Promise.emit (/home/sankar/Cloud/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promis       e.js:84:38)
  at Promise.fulfill (/home/sankar/Cloud/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promis      e.js:97:20)
  at /home/sankar/Cloud/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1400:13
  at model.Document.init (/home /sankar/Cloud/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:254:11)
  at completeOne (/home/sankar/Cloud/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1398:10)
  at Object.cb (/home/sankar/Cloud/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1155:11)
  at Object._onImmediate (/home/sankar/Cloud/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mquery/lib/utils.js      :137:16)
```

I am getting this error only when i am trying to signin with correct details means for incorrect username it is explicitly throwing error,but for not for correct credintials.
It is working fine for SignUp .

Local.js code:

```
   var passport = require('passport'),
   LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy,
   User = require('mongoose').model('User');

 module.exports = function()
 {
 passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) 
 {
    User.findOne(
    {
        username: username
    },
    function(err, user)
    {
        if (err) 
        {
            return done(err);
        }
        if (!user) 
        {
            return done(null, false, 
            {
                message: 'Unknown user'
            });
        }
        if (!(user.authenticate(password))) 
        {
            return done(null, false, 
            {
                message: 'Invalid password'
            });
        }
        return done(null, user);
    });
  }));
  }
```

In my user.js i have added the method for authentication.

```
  UserSchema.methods.hashPassword = function(password) {
  return crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 10000,
  64).toString('base64');
  };
  UserSchema.methods.authenticate = function(password) {
  return this.password === this.hashPassword(password);
  };
```

Comment: Shouldn't you compare user.password to password? I don't know what the  authenticate is supposed to do but replacing the above call with `if( user.password !== password)` should work.

Comment: Yes, I did the comparison in my user.js file.I have added the code above , how i am comparing the password

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mongoose instance method is undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10724876/mongoose-instance-method-is-undefined)

Comment: i gone through that question but it didn't solve my problem.In my case server is stopping automatically when i am trying to login

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined **authenticate** method. Attach it to your schema:

```
var user= mongoose.Schema({ 
    username: 'string',
    password: 'string'
});
authSchema.methods.authenticate = function( pwd ) {
    return ( this.password === pwd );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for responding and sorry i forgot to add the authenticate method. Now i have added the authenticate method which is already present in my user.js file.